# Problem with VS showing Error in errorlist with generic Blazor View

Tags: c#, blazor

Error message: Found markup element with unexpected name 'TFilterViewModel' If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.

This error message should not be displayed in error list, as the generic type TFilterViewModel has the constraint ComponentBase

additionally there is NO build Error. Build is alsways successful. But VS shows an error in error list and underlines the following line red:

```
<TFilterViewModel ViewModel="@ViewModel" />
```

Just a display bug?

ViewModelFilter.razor

```
@using Common.Server.UI.ViewModels.Bases

@typeparam TModel
@typeparam TFilterViewModel

<h5><input type="checkbox" @bind="@FilterViewModel!.ShowFilter" disabled="@Disabled" />@Res.LabelFilter</h5>
@if (FilterViewModel.ShowFilter)
{
    <TFilterViewModel ViewModel="@ViewModel" /> // Error: Found markup element with unexpected name 'TFilterViewModel' (...)
}

@code
{
#nullable disable
    [Parameter] public IFilteredListViewModel<TFilterViewModel> FilterViewModel { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Disabled { get; set; }
#nullable restore
}
```

ViewModelFilter.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Common.Server.UI.Controls
{
    public interface IViewModelComponentBase<TModel>
    {
        public TModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ViewModelFilter<TModel, TFilterViewModel> : ComponentBase
        where TFilterViewModel : ComponentBase, IViewModelComponentBase<TModel>
    { }
}
```

Comment: These things happen more often than not when I'm developing Blazor apps, my colleagues have the same experiences. Sometimes a clean build will suffice, other times I need to close VS completely and restart is before these strange messages go away. I'm sorry I don't really have any better solutions, but I'm sure this will eventually be resolved with updates to VS.

Comment: closing VS solves the issue... but it's annoying. I am alyways up-to-date with VS

Answer (score 0):

My team ran into this a few times.

**Some things that have worked for us are to:**

1. Delete the obj and bin folders (temporary fix; don't worry they'll return when you build your solution next).
2. Restart VS (temporary fix).
3. Upgrade to the latest VS2022 (Haven't had this issue with VS2022-17.2.3; this option worked wonders for my team).